# How to zoom in and out when UISearchbar is active/inactive?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

My code as below:-

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = TRUE;
    _r = self.view.frame;
    _r.origin.y = -44;
    _r.size.height += 44;
    self.view.frame = _r;

    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];

    return YES;
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *) searchBar
{

    NSLog(@"cancel button pressed");
    //This'll Hide The cancelButton with Animation
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
    _r.origin.y = 44;
    _r.size.height -= 44;
    self.view.frame = _r;
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    //remaining Code'll go here
}
```

The code above did not work as intended. It spoiled the view instead of zooming in and out. It became as the image below when "Cancel" button is pressed. How can I have a perfect zoom in and out effect such as Apple's search bar in iPhone's "Settings".
[Spoiled view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHe9R.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `CGAffineTransform` in the UISearchBar object.

```
CGFloat zoomIn = 1, zoomOut = .1;

CGAffineTransform tfIn = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(zoomIn, zoomIn);
CGAffineTransform tfOut = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(zoomOut, zoomOut);

[UIView animateWithDuration: .2 delay: 0 options: 0 animations: ^{
    self.transform = tfIn;

} completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
    // Nothing
}];

// Action from button to zoom out
self.transform = tfOut;
```